# Trying to remove square brackets and apostrophe's dataframe list when i output to excel

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I am successful, to output my dataframe into excel, but there are extra unwanted brackets and apostrophe i want to remove.

```
data1 = [x.split(',') for x in self.ismyFirstrange1]
    data2 = [y.split(',') for y in self.isFirst1]
    dataf1 = pd.DataFrame({'range 2456500 - 2556499': data1})
    dataf2 = pd.DataFrame({'range 2456500 - 2556499': data2})
    frames = [dataf1, dataf2]


    result = pd.concat(frames, keys=['firstRange', 'secondRange'], axis=1, join='inner')
    pprint(result)

    df = pd.DataFrame(result)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outputbarcode.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')

    writer.save()
```

output to excel looks like this:

```
       A
 1    ['2506588']
 2    ['2540181']
 3    ['2553486']
 4    ['2540181']
 5    ['2540389']
 6    ['2553384']
```

i want it

```
      A
 1    2506588
 2    2540181
 3    2553486
 4    2540181
 5    2540389
 6    2553384
```

I i realise, i need to str, replace it somewhere, but not sure how it is done.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to preprocess your first column:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str[0].astype(int)
```

Comment: i converted them to strings, i expect out to be str.

Comment: @JohnOlegario DON'T convert data to string prematurely - you will loose information you can need to convert the data if necessary.

Comment: They are converted so I can split,  the data within,  them.  it is necessary,  and I'm successful of what I need to achieve,  it's just square brackets comes along when I output to excel

Answer (score 0):

If values are lists:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].str[0].astype(int)
```

And if strings:

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].str.strip('[]').astype(int)
```

You can check it by:

```
print (type(df['column name'].iloc[0]))
```

Also you can omit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

because `result` is `DataFrame` too.

So:

```
result = pd.concat(frames, keys=['firstRange', 'secondRange'], axis=1, join='inner')
#if need reset index to default
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)
pprint(result)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outputbarcode.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: dataframe object has no attribute col?

Comment: col is column name

Comment: What return `pprint(result.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: it is giving me an error Dataframe has no attribute str